# Actual value is also replaced after applied isNll in spark sql

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I am trying to replace null values with default value as unknown. After applied this isNull condition on particular column birthplace, actual value is also replacing with column name birthplace.

I have given small snippet of code as well.
      can someone help on this issue.

```
val xmlDF = sqlContext.read.format("xml").option("rowTag","person").load("src/main/resources/ages.xml")

xmlDF.printSchema()

val excolDF = xmlDF.select(xmlDF("age._VALUE").alias("age"),col("age._birthplace").as("birthplace"),column("age._born").as("born"),$"name")

val nulDF = excolDF.withColumn("birthplace",when(col("birthplace").isNull,"Unknown").otherwise("birthplace"))

nulDF.show()
```

**Result**

```
| 25|birthplace|1990-02-24|Hyukjin|

| 30|   Unknown|1985-01-01|   Lars|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `nullDF` line as below:

```
val nulDF = excolDF.withColumn("birthplace",when(col("birthplace").isNull,"Unknown").otherwise(col("birthplace"))
```